# get cell value based on header string and selected row

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

For example, I have a PyQt QTableWidget which has 3 columns and 2 rows.
The column headers are labeled A, B, and C.

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

This is the excerpt from my current source:

```
class myform(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(myform, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_mygui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.mytablewidget.cellClicked.connect(self.cell_was_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot() # prevents executing following function twice
    def cell_was_clicked(self):
        row = self.ui.mytablewidget.currentItem().row()
        print "row=",row
        col = self.ui.mytablewidget.currentItem().column()
        print "col=",col
        item = self.ui.mytablewidget.horizontalHeaderItem(col).text()
        print "item=",item
```

My code works and when I select a row in my table.. I get the correct row and col numbers from the selection.

What is the code needed to return a cell value for the selected row given a specified header name?  If I select row 2 cell 1 ... how can I get the cell value of column C on the same row?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you do that you got: "local variable 'matchcol' referenced before assignment"

To fix that you should return the cell inside if loop:

```
#===================================================================
# given a tablewidget which has a selected row...
# return the column value in the same row which corresponds to a given column name
# fyi: columnname is case sensitive
#===================================================================

def getsamerowcell(widget,columnname):

    row = widget.currentItem().row()
    # col = widget.currentItem().column()

    # loop through headers and find column number for given column name
    headercount = widget.columnCount()
    for x in range(headercount):
        headertext = widget.horizontalHeaderItem(x).text()
        if columnname == headertext:
            cell = widget.item(row, x).text()  # get cell at row, col
            return cell
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the row and column of the cell, you can use [QTableWidget.item](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#item) to get the QTableWidgetItem, from which you can get the [text](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#text) and/or the stored [data](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#data).

So in your slot, if you have row and column, you can see which letter this column corresponds to, and from there determine which column you want to get the data from.